# Generic method working for one class but not the other, with the same interface

Tags: c#, interface, generic-method

I have two classes

```
[DataContract]
public class HiveReference : IGUID
{
    [BsonId]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid GUID{ get; set; }
    ....
}
...

[DataContract]
public class HiveByteChunk : IGUID
{
    [DataMember]
    [BsonId]
    public Guid GUID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My interface ...

```
public interface IGUID
{
    Guid GUID {get;set;}
}
```

Then I have an extension method ...

```
public static void InsertIfNotExists<T>(this T member) where T: IGUID
{
    if (!(member).Exists())
    {
        member.Insert();
    }
}

public static void Insert(this object member) 
{
    DBHelper.Insert(member);
}
```

Then my implementation code ...

```
HiveReference hf = new HiveReference();
hf.InsertIfNotExists();

HiveByteChunk chunk = new HiveByteChunk();
chunk.InsertIfNotExists();
```

The last line breaks, with this compiler error:

```
Error   CS0311
    The type 'HiveLibrary.HiveBytes.HiveByteChunk' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Extensions.InsertIfNotExists<T>(T)'.
    There is no implicit reference conversion from 'HiveLibrary.HiveBytes.HiveByteChunk' to 'HiveLibrary.IGUID'.
```

If both classes implements the interface, why would the first one be able to call the extension, but not the last? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Well, actually this is not possible. You surely missed something which is also missing in your post. Can you try to generate a [mcve] (post the minimal but complete code to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Do both classes implement `HiveLibrary.IGUID`?

Comment: weird that the order of the [DataMember] [BsonId] would make a difference... do you have [DataContract] above both? (you have ... above the other, can't tell)

Comment: @KevinCook - the order of attributes doesn't matter - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2244163/1364007), for example.

Comment: @RenéVogt, not from this project, but I'll try recreating the scenario in a smaller project.

Comment: @KevinCook, I've changed the order, no effect.And yes, sorry, ill edit the code, but both do implement DataContract

Comment: @WaiHaLee, yes. both classes implement the interface

Comment: What if you removed some of the 'chaff' (attributes on the two types and their properties, the body of `InsertIfNotExists`, and the `Insert` method)?

Comment: @WaiHaLee, I'm not sure I completely understand what you're saying. There are no attributes on the Insert and InsertIfNotExists methods, however, I removed the content from the method itself, without any change.

Comment: I edited my comment - basically I wanted confirm that the attributes being present were unrelated to the problem. Likewise, the *contents* of `InsertIfNotExists` likely isn't relevant since it's a compiler error. In that case, the `Insert` method probably won't be relevant either.

Comment: Could it be that there is another `IGUID` in a different namespace and `HiveByteChunk` implements that?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSchremser , as I was busy butchering away code, I noticed exactly what you mentioned ... I had a duplicate IGUID interface hidden in the bottom of the class that I was testing with earlier, and forgot to remove.

Comment: I cut and paste this set of classes and outside of not knowing what the member.exists() functionality was, the code compiled and I got into the extension method just fine. I see you got your answer above now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a duplicate interface, in a different namespace. Once I removed that, everything worked as intended.